# Blackberry development: choose sdk

Tags: blackberry

I have installed the Java plugin for Eclipse Galileo on Windows. However, i don't know how to choose the sdk in Eclipse. any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are any of your questions not answered here? http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp

Comment: not, because i don't know how to choose the sdk in eclipse..

Comment: The above link is for the plugin download itself, but that page also links to the documentation that explains exactly how to configure and use the plugin in Eclipse. Did you read that documentation yet? http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install earlier SDKs by following instructions located here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp
Unfortunately the SDKs don't go any earlier than 4.5.0, so for legacy development you might want to try googling **BlackBerry JDE**, if my memory serves me right.

I hope this is of any help

Comment: yeah but how can i select 4.5 in eclipse? thanks! i have all the sdk's downloaded.

Comment: You don't even have to download the sdk's yourself, eclipse will do that for you! Just follow steps 1-9 under "installation instructions" in the link I provided and choose "BlackBerry Java SDK Version 4.5" in step 3.